# Path to home in Magento?

Tags: php, static-block

I need to set images from the Magento media folder but index.php keeps getting in the way and since I'm going to be moving this dev site to another production URL, I can't just use hard paths in this case.

In Wordpress/Drupal I can set a link like `<img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/media/image-name.jpg" />` but I can't find anything similar to that for Magento.

I'm needing this for the static blocks section if that makes a difference. When I try to set relative links to `http://mysite.com/media/image-name.jpg` I end up with `http://mysite.com/index.php/media/image-name.jpg` which of course results in 404.

What do I need to put in static blocks that will reference the main site without the index.php?

Comment: your base url include index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the canonical way to get the media url is:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl('media');
```

so you in phtml you can do

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media'); ?>image-name.jpg" />
```

but in static blocks you need template syntax:

```
{{media url='image-name.jpg'}}
```

Comment: Excellent. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>media/image-name.jpg" />
```

Take a look on this [article](http://jagdeepbanga.com/blog/magento-get-base-url-skin-url-media-url-js-url-store-url-and-current-url.html). It lists all type of url methods.